# Interaction term alters degrees of freedom for main effects in glmmTMB model

Tags: interaction, binomial-distribution, glmm, degrees-of-freedom, glmmtmb

I am using the glmmTMB package to test whether the probability of a seed remaining dormant in the soil (binary variable) depends on the population it comes from (fixed effect, 8 levels of population), the supply of water it received (fixed effect, 2 levels of watering treatment), as well as the weight of the seed as measured beforehand (fixed effect, continuous variable). The maternal plant the seed came from, or family, is treated as a random effect (nested within population).

`dormant.model.noint<-glmmTMB(dormant ~ population + watertreatment + seedmass + (1|population:family), + family=list(family="binomial",link="logit"), data = data)`

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: dormant
                 Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
population     53.3732  7  3.128e-09 ***
watertreatment  5.6821  1    0.01714 *  
seedmass        4.3708  1    0.03656 *
```

I would like to test whether responses to watering treatment differ between populations, and so included the watering treatment x population interaction. However, when I do so, the degrees of freedom for the main effects (population and watering treatment) increase.

`dormant.model.int<-glmmTMB(dormant ~ population * watertreatment + seedmass + (1|population:family),+ family=list(family="binomial",link="logit"), data = data)`

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: dormant
                            Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
population                50.7801 13  2.189e-06 ***
watertreatment             8.4274  7    0.29642    
seedmass                   4.0435  1    0.04434 *  
population:watertreatment  3.4938  7    0.83588
```

I am wondering if anyone could explain why this is happening, and perhaps give advice on how to fix this? I should also note that same thing **does not** occur for models of another response variable (emergence time) with nlme when including the interaction term (with the exact same fixed and random effects). Thank you for reading!

Comment: that's quite strange, seems like a bug.  Could you post data somewhere to make this a reproducible example?

Comment: Data: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QaVZ2PYi7fMa8YiPKuilXln_UQ0mrIF_3fnlfgTqOE4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just posted a link to issue [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/608) so it doesn't fall through the cracks ...

Comment: Thank you so much!